# Return JSON containing javascript functions from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I have a JSON-like data structure (which I don't want to change) that is currently generated by an `.aspx` file spitting out javascript. It looks like .NET ate jQuery for lunch, and then vomited...

I'd like to rewrite the entire thing to an MVC controller action that returns a `JsonResult`, basically by building up an anonymous object and pass it to `return Json(data)`.

However, I can't figure out how to construct the C# object when some of the properties on the JSON object I want to build are actually JavaScript functions. How do I do that?

Example:

I want to create the following JSON-like object:

```
{
    id: 55, 
    name: 'john smith', 
    age: 32,
    dostuff: aPredefinedFunctionHandle,
    isOlderThan: function(other) { return age > other.age } 
}
```

You see that I want to be able to specify both function handles to JavaScript functions that I have defined elsewhere (in `.js` files, usually) and that I want to define new inline functions.

I know how to build part of that object in C#:

```
var data = new { id = 55, name = "john smith", age = 32 };
return Json(data);
```

Is there any good way to do also the rest of it?

Comment: JSON explicitly excludes functions because it isn't meant to be a JavaScript-only data structure (despite the JS in the name). So we should not include function name in JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no built-in type in .NET that maps to javascript function.** So you may have to create a custom type that represents a function and you have to do the serialization yourself.

Something like this..

```
public class JsFunction
{
   public string FunctionString{get; set;}
}

new
{
    id = 55, 
    name = 'john smith', 
    age = 32,
    dostuff = new JsFunction{ FunctionString = "aPredefinedFunctionHandle" },
    isOlderThan = new JsFunction{ FunctionString = "function(other) { return age > 
                    other.age" } 
}
```

On serialization you may have to check the type of the value and write the `FunctionString` directly into the response without double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

JSON explicitly excludes functions because it isn't meant to be a JavaScript-only data structure (despite the JS in the name). So we should not include function name in JSON

Comment: OK, I stand corrected. But then it's not JSON I want - just something "JSON-like"... so I still wonder how to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

JSON excludes functions. It sounds like you want to encapsulate your data into a class. How about something like the following:

```
function Person(data) {
   this.id = data.id;
   this.name = data.name;
   this.age = data.age;
   this.isOlderThan = function(other) { return this.age > other.age };

}
```

Comment: How is it invalid Javascript syntax?